# How can I customize my Sign Up form using Auth0?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, oauth, authorization

I have integrated Auth0 on heroku for authentication of users using Node.js and express-js. Now I need to customize signup form. I can do this using Auth0 API for custom signup. Like they say here i.e. https://auth0.com/docs/custom-signup. But the problem is that then user can't login through social logins like gmail, facebook etc. I need to enable social logins and also have a custom signup form. I would be really grateful if you would help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use additionalSignUpFields available for lock version 10. 
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#additionalsignupfields-array-

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your answer further, the link may get unreachable in the future and your answer lack of enough info. For further info, please visit [how to answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)